# Session Fixation- Getting an error while accessing value in a session

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm writing a grails application which uses Spring Security Plugins. I turned on the following attribute for the spring security plugin

> grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = true
>   grails.plugins.springsecurity.SessionFixationPrevention.migrate = true
>   grails.plugins.springsecurity.SessionFixationPrevention.alwaysCreateSession
>   = true

I have the following code in my AuthenticationProvider

> def session =
>   RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession()
>
> session.key = "Some Value"

Now after Authentication my code in the loginSuccess method of my RememberMeService class gets called and when I try to get the value in the session which was placed, I get this error

j

> ava.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already
>   invalidated   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:110)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession.getAttribute(GrailsHttpSession.java:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:54)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.ServletsGrailsPlugin$_closure1_closure2.doCall(ServletsGrailsPlugin.groovy:44)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaMethod.invoke(ClosureMetaMethod.java:80)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1109)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getProperty(InvokerHelper.java:161)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:33)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
>     at
>   com.teslagovernment.security.TabulaeRememberMeServices.loginSuccess(TabulaeRememberMeServices.groovy:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:294)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.filter.GrailsReloadServletFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsReloadServletFilter.java:104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)

My question is why is this happening and how can I set data in my AuthenticationProvider
 which I can access in my RememberMeService ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try issuing a redirect immediately after authenticating, and before accessing any copied session properties. The session variable in your service right after authentication may still be referring to the old session from the request context. A redirect will refresh the request context.

Otherwise, you can store any additional properties in your spring security principal object within your AuthenticationProvider. Outside your provider, you can access the principal via the springSecurityService, which is inside the applicationContext:

```
MyPrincipalObject obj = springSecurityService.principal
def key = obj.key
```

Comment: How can I get my response object in the AuthenticationPRovider. I don't see anything there, unless they are injected by default.

Comment: Your provider's authenticate method should return an object which implements org.springframework.security.core.Authentication. The principal is a property of the Authentication object.